# Is a database either a population or sample population?

Tags: terminology

I am writing a paper, and I hit a singular obstacle. What are databases in statistics nomenclature? How do we call databases in statistics vernacular? Populations or sample population or databases or just datasets

Obviously, statisticians and data scientists make heavy use of the term dataset in statistical analysis, statistical learning (e.g. sample bootstrap), and machine learning.

However, datasets are generally subsets of large databases (many linked data objects), but in the machine learning literature we notice few references of the database information system in statistical terms, even though datasets are made of disparate data-driven applications that often rely on a form of database to store data points. Thus, my question. If you can link some papers and how they use the term *database* in statistical terms, that will be useful. I want to be explicit that the focus of this question is on the statistician/data scientist viewpoint and not that of a database administrator or developer.

Answer (score 3):

A database can be a sample or a population.

Using an example from data science, it makes sense to talk about *the population of users who logged into the service in the month of January 2024*.  However, data from those users is a sample from a larger population (the population of users who *could have logged in*).

It depends on the question you're attempting to answer.

Comment: (and it may also be neither a sample or a population)